# Is there any GPS / Geolocation / way to get and use coordinates In JAVA for desktop apps?

Tags: java, gps, location

I want to know if there's any way to use gps sensor of computer with JAVA, Not for android, JAVA only...
To get your computer's actual coordinates.

Edit: Not something like a real sensor, or a physical sensor... something that determinate the coordinates of pc it doesn't matter if is hardware or software...

Comment: Smartphones rely on dedicated GPS chips for geolocation. Desktop and laptop machines are not typically equipped with such hardware.

Comment: This is tantamount to asking us to find / recommend a Java library to read the computer's GPS sensor.  That is a request for an off-site resource and is off-topic.  (Hint: google it ... for your actual platform.)

Comment: I tried to google it but I only get android responses, Thats why I am here...

Comment: You only get Android responses because Android mobile devices have GPS chips. Desktop and laptop machines do not. It's a hardware issue, not a software issue. No amount of Java code is going to deliver hardware dependent functionality unless the required hardware is present.

Comment: I have been looking for c Sharp and actually, I've got answers